# Issue installation of Pyside(1 not 2) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyside

I know that there is a lot of post about Pyside and Ubuntu but I don't find any solution of my problem.
I have Python 2.7 on my Ubuntu 20.04 and it working well. but, for a project that use Pyside, I want to install Pyside 1, not Pyside 2.
I tried different way to install Pyside but without good results.
When I try to install PYside with pip with "sudo pip install Pyside", I obtain this error :

---

```
> Collecting pyside   Using cached PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz (9.3 MB)
>     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>      command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nh_tjfz3/pyside/setup.py'"'"';
> __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nh_tjfz3/pyside/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-nh_tjfz3/pyside/pip-egg-info
>          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-nh_tjfz3/pyside/
>     Complete output (1 lines):
>     only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
>     ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for
> full command output.
```

---

So, I don't understand this error, I have the good version of Python (Python 2.7). I tried with another Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and I got the same error. I dont want Pyside 2 but Pyside. He is always possible ton install Pyside or maybe it is obsolete?

Comment: It is **very** obsolete: it's based on Qt4 which is unsupported since 2015. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: Oh ok,I thought it was still possible to install it. The problem is that all the codes constituting my application were made in 2014 based on Pyside1. I tried earlier using pyside2, it blocked directly at the level of the important for Qapplication for example. Is there any solution to install Pyside even if unsopported since 2015 on Ubuntu ?

Comment: It is possible, but it's not easy and might even result in making your system unstable unless you **really** know what you're doing. I strongly suggest you to try to port it to PySide2 (there are many tutorials around); consider that the most important change is that QtGui was splitted into QtWidgets and QtGui (and QApplication is from QtWidgets).

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this. but the error which emerges does not refer to a potential obscolescence. it's weird isn't it?

Comment: it's your responsibility to know about an obsolete package, not the package manager's: python2 is considered obsolete, but it is still required by many systems, so it's still maintained. If you look closely, the error reports that that package is only available for Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3 and 3.4; Ubuntu 20.04 the base python version was 3.8, and you're running that version (see the third line: `/usr/bin/python3`), so you can't install it. Python 2.7 is not installed by default, so the only possible solution would be to try to install python 2.7 and run pip for that python version.